# Giving opacity to Spotlight

Tags: macos, spotlight

I constantly find myself <kbd>⌘CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to do some arithmetic based off numbers I have in front of me. The problem is, as soon as I've entered the first operation, Spotlight expands and opens over some/all of the source of my numbers.

Is there a way I can add an opacity to the Spotlight overlay so I can see through it to the windows below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there's no answer to this, in the new El Capitan there is a slight opacity (although not to see through). However, they have now given us the ability to move spotlight which solves my original issue.

If anyone has a way to replicate this functionality (or my original functionality) in earlier version, please post; but for now, this is your only answer.